# My xamarin.ios app doesn't create .ipa file

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm trying to build a xamarin.ios console application and send it to another member of the development team.  We have an Apple Developer account, but not an Enterprise account.

I went through all the provisioning steps in "Ad-Hoc Distribution for Xamarin.iOS Apps".

Tried real clean.

I get only:
bin\iphone\Debug...
bin\iphone\Release...

...but no .ipa anywhere within the project folder.

In Project > props > iOS IPA Options I set Build iTunes Package Archive (IPA)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are building your application in `Release` mode.

[image]

[image]